# Hibernate Query Returning Duplicate results

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to join 3 tables to get an output. Following are the tables

player_match(match_id,team_id,player_id)

player(player_id,name,......)

team(team_id,name......)

All the tables have equivalent classes assigned.

Following is the SQL query that I am running and getting the correct results.

```
select * from player_match M 
  inner join team T 
    on M.team_id = T.team_id
  inner join player P 
    on P.player_id = M.player_id
  where M.match_id = 335987;
```

I am running the following Named query in PlayerMatch java class. PlayerMatch class has Match and Team objects in it. Both of these objects are mapped @ManyToOne.

```
@NamedQuery(name="getMatchData",query="select PM from PlayerMatch PM "
            + "inner join Team T on PM.teamId = T.teamId "
            + "inner join Player P on PM.playerId = P.playerId "
            + "where PM.matchId = :matchID")
```

When I run the above hibernate query I get 22 results which is correct, but the contents of all the results are the same.

The SQL query that I have mentioned above returns 22 non duplicate rows.

I think I am messing up somewhere in the Hibernate query but can't figure out where.

Comment: Actually, you have 1 player_match, not 22.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you said. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: From Hibernate point of view there is only one `PlayerMatch` entity with given id.

Comment: Actually there will be 22 entries, you see match_id isn't a primary or a unique key. So each match_id field will have 22 entries in the player_match table.
The player_match table contains the team_id and player_id, I am using these fields to get the details from respective tables i.e team and match.

Comment: I don't think I follow. You want to retrieve all `PlayerMatch`es with `match_id=335987`, right? Why not simply use `SELECT pm FROM PlayerMatch pm JOIN WHERE pm.match_id = 335987`? What do you need the other joins for?

Comment: I solved, the issue. The primary key wasn't defined correctly, hence I was getting duplicate results. Turns out that the query was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your HQL query is structured similarly to an SQL query. You shouldn't need to specify the 'on' conditions as they are derived from the hibernate schema.

See hibernate documentation for more info on hql joins: 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins